# How to use javascript to find the (svg) position of preexisting elements in an inline svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use javascript to draw lines between different svg elements.
The svg elements are in a preexisting svg image (created with inkScape) which is loaded inline.

I am getting hung up finding the proper coordinates of the existing svg elements relative to the svg document itself for purposes of drawing the lines.

See the following snippet for example. 
I'm trying to implement the FindSVGPosition function.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id^=sys_]").addClass("sysGroup");
  $(".sysGroup").click(function(e) {
    var sysElement = $(this);
    var id = $(sysElement).attr("id");
    var sysName = id.substr(4);
    var metaNameId = "meta_" + sysName;
    var metaElmnt = $("#" + metaNameId);
    if (metaElmnt != undefined) {
      //showCenter('system1');
      if ($(metaElmnt).is(":visible")) {
        $(metaElmnt).hide("fast");
      } else {
        var position = findDOMPosition(sysName);
        $(metaElmnt).css(
          "top",
          window.scrollY + position.height + position.y + 2
        );
        $(metaElmnt).css("left", window.scrollX + position.x);
        $(metaElmnt).show("fast");
      }
    }
  });

  function drawPath(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var pathBetween = findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName);
    var newLine = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "line"
    );
    newLine.setAttribute(
      "id",
      pathBetween.fromSystemName + "_" + pathBetween.toSystemName
    );
    newLine.setAttribute("x1", pathBetween.fromX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y1", pathBetween.fromY);
    newLine.setAttribute("x2", pathBetween.toX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y2", pathBetween.toY);
    newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
    $("#svg8").append(newLine);
    return pathBetween;
  }

  function findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var fromPosition = findSVGPosition(fromSystemName);
    var toPosition = findSVGPosition(toSystemName);
    if (fromPosition == null || toPosition == null) return null;

    //center to center
    var response = {
      fromSystem: fromSystemName,
      fromX: fromPosition.x + fromPosition.width / 2,
      fromY: fromPosition.top + fromPosition.height / 2,
      fromSide: "center",
      toSystem: toSystemName,
      toX: toPosition.x + toPosition.width / 2,
      toY: toPosition.top + toPosition.height / 2,
      toSide: "center"
    };
    return response;
  }

  function findSVGPosition(systemName) {
    //d.x, d.y, d.top, d.right, d.bottom, d.height
    
  }
  
  function findDOMPosition(systemName) {
    //d.x, d.y, d.top, d.right, d.bottom, d.height
    var systemElement = $("#sys_" + systemName);
    if (systemElement == null) return null;
    return $(systemElement)
      .get(0)
      .getBoundingClientRect();
  }
});
```

```css
#systemDiagram{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.meta{
  width: 350px;
  font-size: smaller;
}
p, ul{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.metaHeader{
  font-size: large;  
}
text:hover{
  cursor: default;
}
.sysGroup:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sysGroup text:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#info-box, .meta {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #eaeded;
  border: 2px solid #239b56;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <p>lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum. lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum. lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum.</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum. lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum. lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem other ipsum.</p>  
  
</div>
<div id="info-box"></div>
<div class="meta" id="meta_system1">
  <div><span class="metaHeader">Description</span></div>
  <p>description</p>
</div>  
<div class="meta" id="meta_system2">
  <div>Something here for system2</div>
</div>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="14in"
   height="8.5in"
   viewBox="0 0 355.6 215.9"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.02.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.0404412"
     inkscape:cx="485.6749"
     inkscape:cy="543.80097"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     units="in" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="systemGroups" />
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer3"
     inkscape:label="ancillary"
     style="display:none"
     sodipodi:insensitive="true">
    <rect
       style="display:inline;opacity:0.4;fill:#ffcc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.23668619"
       id="rect175"
       width="115.25188"
       height="27.459745"
       x="127.27588"
       y="14.725033" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:label="systems"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-81.1)"
     style="display:inline">
    <g
       id="sys_system1"
       transform="translate(15.595292,0.08990834)"
       inkscape:label="#g164">
      <rect
         style="fill:#000080;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1389997"
         y="102.51232"
         x="48.695206"
         height="12.662203"
         width="23.878363"
         id="rect47"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51"
         y="110.01817"
         x="51.767498"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="110.01817"
           x="51.767498"
           id="tspan49"
           sodipodi:role="line">System1</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect95"
       width="177.46696"
       height="27.528765"
       x="10.156241"
       y="95.21151" />
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect97"
       width="133.36749"
       height="39.555889"
       x="19.777945"
       y="94.142426" />
    <g
       id="sys_system2"
       inkscape:label="#g90"
       transform="translate(-5.0449918)">
      <rect
         style="fill:#aa8800;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.13352577"
         y="139.75128"
         x="70.257324"
         height="12.662203"
         width="22.034693"
         id="rect47-1"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51-2"
         y="147.25714"
         x="73.32962"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="147.25714"
           x="73.32962"
           id="tspan49-8"
           sodipodi:role="line">System2</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I am able to find the coordinates of the svg elements relative to the DOM and position a div correctly under those elements.

I am able to draw a line on the svg using javascript at arbitrary start & endpoints.

I am unable to access the svg attributes (x,y,height,width) of the existing svg elements relative to the svg image.

Most of the examples I can find utilize the contentDocument of the svg element. But in my case, no matter what I've tried - the contentDocument is null.

Since I'm not triggering this action on load of the page - I'm confident that the svg should be fully loaded in the dom when the code runs.

It seems like this should be easily possible without any libraries, but I've been trying to figure it out for too long, and could really use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Firstly, you are making things hard for yourself because of all the `transform` attributes on the elements in the SVG.  My first recommendation would be to get rid of them all.

   The easiest way to do that in Inkscape is to ungroup and then regroup the objects.
2. If you do that, your function is simple:

   ```
   function findSVGPosition(systemName) {
     return document.getElementById(systemName).getBBox();
   }
   ```

   The `getBBox()` function returns the bounding box of the SVG element.  But the bounding box does not account for the transforms on the element or its parent elements.  The bounds won't be useful if there are transforms. That's the reason why we got rid of them in step #1.
3. Next, fix the typos in `findPathBetween()`: The `.top` should `.y`.
4. Finally, you need to call the `drawPath()` function.

   ```
   drawPath('sys_system1', 'sys_system2');
   ```
5. But the line is on top of the boxes.  So you'll probably want to do a `.prepend()` , instead of an `.append()`.  So that the line is before - and thus underneath -  the boxes.

   ```
   $("#svg8").prepend(newLine);
   ```

Then you end up with this.

```js
function drawPath(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var pathBetween = findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName);
    var newLine = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "line"
    );
    newLine.setAttribute(
      "id",
      pathBetween.fromSystemName + "_" + pathBetween.toSystemName
    );
    newLine.setAttribute("x1", pathBetween.fromX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y1", pathBetween.fromY);
    newLine.setAttribute("x2", pathBetween.toX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y2", pathBetween.toY);
    newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
    $("#svg8").prepend(newLine);
    return pathBetween;
  }

  function findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var fromPosition = findSVGPosition(fromSystemName);
    var toPosition = findSVGPosition(toSystemName);
    if (fromPosition == null || toPosition == null) return null;

    //center to center
    var response = {
      fromSystem: fromSystemName,
      fromX: fromPosition.x + fromPosition.width / 2,
      fromY: fromPosition.y + fromPosition.height / 2,
      fromSide: "center",
      toSystem: toSystemName,
      toX: toPosition.x + toPosition.width / 2,
      toY: toPosition.y + toPosition.height / 2,
      toSide: "center"
    };
    return response;
  }

  function findSVGPosition(systemName) {
    return document.getElementById(systemName).getBBox();
  }
  
  
  
  drawPath('sys_system1', 'sys_system2');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="14in"
   height="8.5in"
   viewBox="0 0 355.6 215.9"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)"
   sodipodi:docname="line.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.0404412"
     inkscape:cx="166.09894"
     inkscape:cy="543.80097"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg8"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1378"
     inkscape:window-x="1592"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     units="in" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="systemGroups"
     style="display:inline" />
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer3"
     inkscape:label="ancillary"
     style="display:none"
     sodipodi:insensitive="true">
    <rect
       style="display:inline;opacity:0.4;fill:#ffcc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.23668619"
       id="rect175"
       width="115.25188"
       height="27.459745"
       x="127.27588"
       y="14.725033" />
  </g>
  <g
     id="g864"
     inkscape:label="systems">
    <g
       id="sys_system1">
      <rect
         style="fill:#000080;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1389997"
         y="21.502226"
         x="64.290497"
         height="12.662203"
         width="23.878363"
         id="rect47"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51"
         y="29.008078"
         x="67.362793"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="29.008078"
           x="67.362793"
           id="tspan49"
           sodipodi:role="line">System1</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect95"
       width="177.46696"
       height="27.528765"
       x="10.156241"
       y="14.111509" />
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect97"
       width="133.36749"
       height="39.555889"
       x="19.777945"
       y="13.042425" />
    <g
       id="sys_system2">
      <rect
         style="fill:#aa8800;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.13352577"
         y="58.651283"
         x="65.212334"
         height="12.662203"
         width="22.034693"
         id="rect47-1"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51-2"
         y="66.157143"
         x="68.28463"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="66.157143"
           x="68.28463"
           id="tspan49-8"
           sodipodi:role="line">System2</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

## Update - better version

Here's a better version that doesn't require you to remobve all the transforms in Inkscape.

In this version, we pick our line endpoints, then use `getCTM()` to find the total transform from the element to the page.

The slight complication is that `getCTM()` includes all the transformations.  Including the transform that is caused by the `viewBox` scaling.  But we don't want the transform to include that last step.  So, to fix that, what we do is call `getCTM` for the root `<svg>` element, then use that to cancel out the `viewBox` part of the transform.

```js
function drawPath(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var pathBetween = findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName);
    var newLine = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "line"
    );
    newLine.setAttribute(
      "id",
      pathBetween.fromSystem + "_" + pathBetween.toSystem
    );
    newLine.setAttribute("x1", pathBetween.fromX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y1", pathBetween.fromY);
    newLine.setAttribute("x2", pathBetween.toX);
    newLine.setAttribute("y2", pathBetween.toY);
    newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
    $("#svg8").prepend(newLine);
    return pathBetween;
  }

  function findPathBetween(fromSystemName, toSystemName) {
    var fromPosition = findSVGPosition(fromSystemName);
    var toPosition = findSVGPosition(toSystemName);
    if (fromPosition == null || toPosition == null) return null;

    //center to center
    var response = {
      fromSystem: fromSystemName,
      fromX: fromPosition.x,
      fromY: fromPosition.y,
      fromSide: "center",
      toSystem: toSystemName,
      toX: toPosition.x,
      toY: toPosition.y,
      toSide: "center"
    };
    return response;
  }

  function findSVGPosition(systemName) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(systemName);
    var bbox = elem.getBBox();
    var point = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
    point.y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
    var elemToViewportTransform = elem.getCTM();  // includes SVG scaling
    var svgToViewportTransform = getViewportTransform(elem);
    return point.matrixTransform(elemToViewportTransform)  // apply elem transform
                .matrixTransform(svgToViewportTransform.inverse());  // but take off the svg scaling
  }
  
  function getViewportTransform(elem) {
    if (elem.ownerSVGElement.getCTM) {
      var result = elem.ownerSVGElement.getCTM()
      if (result != null)
        return result;
    }
    // Workaround for Firefox and other browsers that don't support transform
    // on the `<svg> element yet (it's an SVG2 thing).
    var svg = elem.ownerSVGElement;
    var g = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "g");
    svg.appendChild(g);
    var result = g.getCTM();
    svg.removeChild(g);
    return result;
  }
  
  drawPath('sys_system1', 'sys_system2');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="14in"
   height="8.5in"
   viewBox="0 0 355.6 215.9"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.02.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.0404412"
     inkscape:cx="485.6749"
     inkscape:cy="543.80097"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     units="in" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="systemGroups" />
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer3"
     inkscape:label="ancillary"
     style="display:none"
     sodipodi:insensitive="true">
    <rect
       style="display:inline;opacity:0.4;fill:#ffcc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.23668619"
       id="rect175"
       width="115.25188"
       height="27.459745"
       x="127.27588"
       y="14.725033" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:label="systems"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-81.1)"
     style="display:inline">
    <g
       id="sys_system1"
       transform="translate(15.595292,0.08990834)"
       inkscape:label="#g164">
      <rect
         style="fill:#000080;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1389997"
         y="102.51232"
         x="48.695206"
         height="12.662203"
         width="23.878363"
         id="rect47"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51"
         y="110.01817"
         x="51.767498"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="110.01817"
           x="51.767498"
           id="tspan49"
           sodipodi:role="line">System1</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect95"
       width="177.46696"
       height="27.528765"
       x="10.156241"
       y="95.21151" />
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       id="rect97"
       width="133.36749"
       height="39.555889"
       x="19.777945"
       y="94.142426" />
    <g
       id="sys_system2"
       inkscape:label="#g90"
       transform="translate(-5.0449918)">
      <rect
         style="fill:#aa8800;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.13352577"
         y="139.75128"
         x="70.257324"
         height="12.662203"
         width="22.034693"
         id="rect47-1"
         inkscape:label="#rect4524-9" />
      <text
         id="text51-2"
         y="147.25714"
         x="73.32962"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
         xml:space="preserve"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:4.23333311px;font-family:'Segoe UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Segoe UI';fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332"
           y="147.25714"
           x="73.32962"
           id="tspan49-8"
           sodipodi:role="line">System2</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Paul LeBeau: Thank you very much for identifying the transforms. I did not add those transforms intentionally. Evidently, they are a bi-product of the way inkscape saves files. 

I had also tried getBBox() but it didn't work with the transforms in place, so those transforms are definitely the culprit here. 

Thanks to your insight, I've been able to track down other stack overflow discussions about this problem - as well as an inkscape forum topic:
https://forum.inkscapecommunity.com/index.php?topic=1610.msg10752#msg10752

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any easy way to solve the transform problem other than ungrouping/regrouping each group which in my particular application is going to be a considerable pain in the butt.

Comment: Oh. That's a pain. Unfortunately ungrouping and regrouping also resets the group id and inkscpe label.  Which make it worse.  Check if there is a plugin for Inkscape that does it.

Comment: I was a bit lazy before because I thought you only had to fix one SVG.  However I've now updated my answer with a solution that works even if there are transforms present.

Comment: Hey Paul, I finally got a chance to look at your improved solution, and when I load the code snippet, it gives me an error (below) I'm really hoping this can work the way you described, it would be a huge saving of work for me. 

  "message": "TypeError: elem.ownerSVGElement.getCTM(...) is null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 196,
  "colno": 34

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I only tested on Chrome. I forgot that FF didn't support `getCTM()` on `<svg>` elements yet. I've updated my example with a workaround.

Comment: Paul! The workaround and new example work perfectly. Thank you very much for all of your help. 
:)